# making simple self join more efficent

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot

I have a table

```
id|level|name
```

level can be 1,2 or 3

what I want to get is:

```
id|lvl1name|lvl2name|lvl3name
```

I'm using the following query

```
SELECT L1."name" as lvl1name, L2."name" as lvl2name, L3."name" as
lvl3name, L1.id
 FROM table as L1
       JOIN table as L2 ON L1.id = L2.id
       JOIN table as L3 ON L2.id = L3.id
       WHERE L1.lvl='1' and L2.lvl='2' and L3.lvl='3';
```

but it is soooooo slow!

there *must* be a better way to do this. please help

for this example I'm using postgres, but I'd be happy to learn some way that is not database feature dependant.

I can't write procedures (read only access), and I select this from a view.

Comment: If you have N rows, this returns N^3 results. That's a pretty monstrous query. How many rows are you dealing with?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use:

```
  SELECT t.id,
         MAX(CASE WHEN t.level = 1 THEN t.name END) AS level1name,
         MAX(CASE WHEN t.level = 2 THEN t.name END) AS level2name,
         MAX(CASE WHEN t.level = 3 THEN t.name END) AS level3name
    FROM YOUR_TABLE t
GROUP BY t.id
```

If you need this to be dynamic, you need to use [dynamic SQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/interactive/ecpg-dynamic.html).

Comment: Nice Work OMG. I found a small observation here. The keyword `END` is missing. The statement should be `MAX(CASE WHEN t.level = 1 THEN t.name END)`.